# what are the opposite of void tags called?

Tags: html, xml

In html, you have the `<img src='...'/>` tags vs. `<div> </div>`

I know that the img tags above are called void / self closing tags. what are the div tags called?  Also, is there an implication between using 1 or the other in  HTML, or other markups beyond HTML (i.e. say XML)?

Comment: [8.1.2. Elements](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements) There are five different kinds of elements: void elements, raw text elements, escapable raw text elements, foreign elements, and normal elements.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML you have void elements. These are elements which cannot have any child nodes. Elements which are not void elements are non-void elements.

In HTML `<img>` is a start tag. `<img />` is a start tag with a `/` in it (the `/` has no special meaning). `<div>` is a start tag. `</div>` is an end tag.

In XML `<foo />` is an empty-element tag. (Start and end tags are the same).

Comment: in xml- does it mean that <foo/> cannot have child nodes?

Comment: @user11235813 — Empty-element syntax in XML is entirely independent of the ability of an element to have child nodes or not (which is determined by the DTD / Schema). Obviously to give it child nodes you would need to use start tag / end tag syntax though.

Answer (score 1):

According to this list https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements on the same page what @corgrath referred to they call them `normal elements`. (Mentioning another 3 categories beyond void and normal).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an official name for those. I would simply call them "non-void elements" if you need to be specific that the elements are not void elements =)

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose the name

> sandwich tag

The reason I don't like "normal tags" is because it's not saying anything at all really.

I think "container tag" makes sense too. But with frameworks like bootstrap, exploiting the `<div class="container"></div>` sandwich, I think it's a bit confusing.

I agree sandwich tag is also a bit foggy, as some people might confuse it with the hamburger menu. But it's the best I could come up with, and I think it kind of sticks. I'll start using it anyway. I also like the idea of sub-sandwiches for nested tags.

Feel free to also use the name for encapsulating XML tags, bb code tags and any other tags that behave a bit sandwichy.