# How to reuse nested elements with href in an SVG background-image?

Tags: xml, svg, workflow, inline, inline-styles

I am creating an SVG background and I want to make the file size smaller by reusing paths.

Because the SVG is applied to an HTML element, called using CSS, like so `background-image: url("filename.svg")` it must be entirely self-contained. In other words, not styled using external CSS, like we could do if it were an *inline SVG*.

I have created a proof-of-concept demo that works well enough and is practical *when the SVG is simple*.

You can run the Code Snippet and see that it's functional. No problem with the result. It's `background-image` compliant.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lightweight SVG Background</title>
  <style>
    /* just example formatting */
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 64px;
    }
    div {
      width: 480px;
      height: 480px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 16px;
      box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      background-color: #fffff6;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    p {      
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #679;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    /* the relevant stuff */
    /* I'm only using base64 for the image URL because I don't see any options to add an SVG file to a Stack Exchange code snippet - sorry that it's awkward */
    .svg-bg {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 90%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="svg-bg">
  <p>lightweight SVG background</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the actual SVG for it, if you view it by itself as a standalone image.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="main_path_grad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="708.1808" y1="346.981" x2="758.9955" y2="462.9193">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#71B9FF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#74CCAF"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <path id="main_path" style="fill:url(#main_path_grad);" d="M975,500.5
        c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-48.4-43.7-66.2-57.2-110.3s32.9-135.4,8-172.9c-17.6-26.6-55.9-16-89.9-52.7L500,500L975,500.5z"/>
</defs>

<g id="background_layer"> <!-- elements within are absolute (defined here and used only once) -->
    <rect id="bg_rect" style="fill:#E6E6E6;" width="100%" height="100%" rx="24"/>
</g>

<g id="main_layer"> <!-- elements within are relative (defined in <defs> and reused) -->

    <!-- upper right -->
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0"/> <!-- original position (not transformed) -->
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(-90)"/>

    <!-- upper left -->
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="rotate(-90)"/>
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1)"/>

    <!-- bottom left -->
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="rotate(180)"/>
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(90)"/>

    <!-- bottom right -->
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="rotate(90)"/>
    <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(180)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

You're probably thinking...

### “it works, so what's the problem?”

Essentially, I want to group the SVG elements in a more intuitive way. This is about **workflow**, and **semantic structure**, and **code readability**.

In order to be able to call the `#main_path` in this example SVG I used `<use>`. I'm a use-user.

And I called it using `href`, which is apparently [the right way to do it now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href).

The core of the issue, it seems, is that `<use>` can't be nested, and using `<svg>` within another `<svg>` is (unless I'm mistaken) not possible when calling the SVG file by `background-image` in an HTML file. Then there is the `<g>` (group) element, but since `href` can't be used on it, that element also won't work for nesting/grouping.

See in the code where I commented `upper right`, `upper left`, etc? That's where I wanted to group the elements. Instead of 8 separate `<use>` elements, it ideally should have been 4 elements (of some kind... I'm not picky about the tag type and am willing to structure in in any way that works). But fiddling with 8 instead of 4 meant additional trial-and-error with the scale/rotate transform combinations, and all of this is doable on a small scale with a simple SVG. But the process doesn't scale up so well when authoring more complex artwork.

If I had just used the unaltered .svg file that Illustrator spit out, `#main_path` alone would have taken up about eight times more space in the file because it wouldn't have been reused.

In this simplified demo, `#main_path` is only 188 characters long. But in my *actual* project's SVG file, that part of the artwork is 64581 characters long. So then multiply that by eight. In this context, hopefully you can see why I care about optimization. If you have to choose a raster image format instead, because the vector artwork's file size is coming out to be larger, that bloat (resulting from redundant instances of what would otherwise be reusable artwork assets) defeats the purpose of the vector-ness.

Utilizing `<use>` is really helpful for minimizing file size.

It's just the inability to nest such elements in a (non-inline) SVG file that is complicating the authoring process. If somebody knows of a way, please spread the enlightenment.

---

### Update

[@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) re:

> “You can point a use at another use, if that's what you need.”

That is something I had tried before posting my question originally, but it didn't work for me. Below I will show what I did. Please let me know if you understand why it fails.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="main_path_grad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="708.1808" y1="346.981" x2="758.9955" y2="462.9193">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#71B9FF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#74CCAF"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <path id="main_path" style="fill:url(#main_path_grad);" d="M975,500.5
        c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-48.4-43.7-66.2-57.2-110.3s32.9-135.4,8-172.9c-17.6-26.6-55.9-16-89.9-52.7L500,500L975,500.5z"/>

    <!-- upper right -->
    <use id="quadrant">
        <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0"/> <!-- original position (not transformed) -->
        <use href="#main_path" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(-90)"/>
    </use>
</defs>

<g id="background_layer"> <!-- elements within are absolute (defined here and used only once) -->
    <rect id="bg_rect" style="fill:#E6E6E6;" width="100%" height="100%" rx="24"/>
</g>

<g id="main_layer"> <!-- elements within are relative (defined in <defs> and reused) -->

    <use href="#quadrant" x="0" y="0"/>
    <use href="#quadrant" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="rotate(90)"/>
    <use href="#quadrant" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="rotate(180)"/>
    <use href="#quadrant" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="rotate(270)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

In the above invalid example, I attempted to define the original upper right ¼ of the design as `#quadrant` within `<defs>` and call it 4 times with `<use>`, then rotated 3 of those 4 (those which are *not* to remain in the default position).

Note that `#quadrant` itself is comprised of 2 `<use>` elements that use `#main_path` - the second being a mirrored and rotated variant of the original.

Furthermore, I tried the `<use>` tag in both an encapsulating format and in a self-closing format. Neither worked:

- Encapsulating (non-void): `<use>content</use>`
- Self-closing (void): `<use content />`

I was under the impression that any given XML/HTML/SVG tag type had to be either an encapsulating ([non-void](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674926/2454914) element), or a self-closing ([void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element) element), but *could not be both*. Since I had only seen `<use>` as self-closing/void... maybe you meant something else by “point at” another `<use>`?

Comment: use may make the file size smaller but it has huge runtime overhead.

Comment: And repeating paths can actually be better, because your content will be delivered GZIP or Brotli compressed. DRY is great for humans but compressors love repetitions.

Comment: @RobertLongson If a `<use>` referencing another `<use>` works, that's great news! (And thank you for sharing.) Unfortunately, it hasn't worked for me. Am I implementing it wrong? Please see the update I added to the end of my question, if you don't mind taking a look.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you. Can you please expand on that concept a little more? (I mean GZIP and Brotli compression, and what someone authoring SVG content should be aware of with regard to those.)

Comment: use pointing at another use means a use element that has a href that leads to another use element.

Comment: Compression is done by the webserver. (contrived example) ``<path d="AAA"/><path d="AAA"/><path d="AAA"/>`` because of the repetitions will be a smaller _transferred_ file than ``<path id="ID" d="AAA"/><use href="#ID"/><use href="#ID"/>``. And as Robert says will run faster

Answer (score 0):

As commented – `<use>` elements though reducing the markup/file size also introduce rendering slow-downs.

So you shouldn't focus too much on the actual markup size.

You can nest use definitions by referencing e.g a `<g>` group containing `<use>` elements

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="main_path_grad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="708.1808" y1="346.981" x2="758.9955" y2="462.9193">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#71B9FF" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#74CCAF" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path id="main_path" fill="url(#main_path_grad)" d="M975,500.5c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-48.4-43.7-66.2-57.2-110.3s32.9-135.4,8-172.9c-17.6-26.6-55.9-16-89.9-52.7L500,500L975,500.5z" />
  </defs>
  <rect id="bg_rect" style="fill:#E6E6E6;" width="100%" height="100%" rx="24" />
  <g id="main_layer">
    <!-- upper right -->
    <g id="quarter">
      <use href="#main_path" />
      <use href="#main_path" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(-90)" />
    </g>
    <use href="#quarter" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(0)" />
    <use href="#quarter" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(90)" />
    <use href="#quarter" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1 1) rotate(180)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The above example

- groups two use instances in a `<g>`
- assigns an ID to the group
- reuses this group via `<use>` instances referencing this group ID

**Rule-of-thumb:** You can't nest any geometry elements (`path`,`rect`, `circle`, `ellipse`, `polygon`, `polyline`, `line`) in another geometry elements. The same applies to `<use>` elements since they have self contained visual properties like a bounding box.

However you can nest "meta" or style related SVG elements like `<title>` or `<animate>` in these elements.

Btw. There is an exploit known as [**SVG Billion Laugh Attack**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75066403/how-to-identify-if-svg-is-consuming-all-browsers-memory-and-snaps-the-window/75091943#75091943) based on nested `<use>` references. So you should try to avoid this concept as it slows down your rendering significantly.